# Apply relative URL to an absolute URL

Tags: python, url

I have an absolute URL, and the URL that a link on that page points to. Is there a builtin function to apply a relative URL to an absolute URL?

Ie. "http://example.com/some/url", "/some/url/I/want/to/go/to" => "http://example.com/some/url/I/want/to/go/to"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`urlparse.urljoin()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) does just this.